# Does Apple reject apps that use images used in Apple's apps?

Tags: ios, iphone, appstore-approval

I'm making an audio player app.

In apple's Music app, if music album or podcast doesn't have artwork, musical note image or podcast icon image are shown instead of artwork.

I want to do same thing.

Can I use images in apple's Music app for my app?
Will apple reject my app?

Do I have to create images of musical note and podcast icon by my self?
Or is it recommended to use apple's images for my app for user experience?

I also want to use history icon, podcast icon, and audiobook icon which are used for tab bar icon in apple's apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reusing toolbar / button icons is fine and Apple probably appreciates UI consistency. Many many apps make use of the Apple icons not included in the core set which are in the app store. Using 'larger' art will be frowned upon though, like splash arts / stock images.

Comment: Thanks! I will create icons by my self instead of using screenshots of apple's icons just in case.
But my icons will be almost the same as apple's for UI consistency.

Comment: The UIKit Artwork Extractor will allow you to extract the images directly using the simulator.

https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Nice tool! thanks! Do many apps are using these images which are extracted directly from simulator?

Answer (score 3):

I did used an image from Apple, and I might say it's rather bizzarre:

1) I uploaded an application for a client that used the "Photos" application icon, and everything went ok, the application was approved.

2) In the next month, I uploaded a new application, for a different client, but with the same logic (only the design was different) and used again the "Photos" application icon. This time the application was reject, stating that I couldn't use Apple icons. After that, I changed the icon and it was approved.

Next time, I won't be using images from Apple. In my case, I didn't had tight deadlines, but if I had, I would be screwed.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the reviewer. Some will let it go and others won't. As far as I am concerned, it isn't worth the risk. Just find/create another graphic to use.

Answer (score 2):

Note, that you don't have legal rights to use Apple's images. They are copyrighted.
Even if the application is not rejected (approver doesn't have to notice the use of copyrighted image), you can have problems later.

Answer (score 1):

Yes apple will reject the application if we use Apple's owned graphics/ property. you can check the guidelines if you need