# Can we use apple photo gallery image in our application?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

[image]
For example (Above Image) the photo gallery image icon.
Can i use this image in my application ?
If i use this image then will my be rejected from the app store ?

Comment: It's really hard to, altough the guide lines state you should not use Apple's artwork in your. However you never know if you will get reject for doing so.

Comment: because some word apple doesn't accept so change your image name.

Comment: Why not create your own?

Comment: The app IFTTT uses several of Apple's own App Icon images in the app.

Comment: Please show us what you are referring to. Which icon? Used how?

Comment: @MarcusAdams I have posted the image please do have a look

Answer (score 2):

If you use Apple's Photos App icon to do anything other than refer to or open Apple's Photos App or Photos Stream, then your app will likely be rejected.

Even then, it's not a good idea to use the icon since the Photos App icon may change:
[image]

Instead, use the [system provided icons](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW41) for referring to the image picker, etc.

Answer (score 1):

No it may not be rejected by apple . Please go through the following link :-

[Does Apple reject apps that use images used in Apple's apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156065/does-apple-reject-if-i-use-images-which-are-used-in-apples-app)

> "Reusing toolbar / button icons is fine and Apple probably appreciates
>   UI consistency. Many many apps make use of the Apple icons not
>   included in the core set which are in the app store. Using 'larger'
>   art will be frowned upon though, like splash arts / stock images."

Please check with the Apple forums. You can use the images but you can't use that image as an icon of the app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am bit confused because the replies in this link state that it will be rejected and u say it will not be rejected.Please help

Answer (score 0):

If your application get rejected for using their icon, just resubmit with your own icon.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but i have a deadline.

Comment: Reading your question again, do you want to use the gallery icon as your own application icon?  Or do you want to use the gallery icon inside your app?

Comment: @Tushar so you have a deadline and for making sure that things go through smoothly you are asking on a community site for reliable answers - you should *really* think about that approach again.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use Photo Gallery icon in Your iphone Application,if you use then apple will reject your application.

[Read this Link](http://www.apple.com/legal/intellectual-property/guidelinesfor3rdparties.html)

Comment: Thanks i will go through this link.