# Reuse iOS system icons

Tags: ios, iphone, icons

I am looking to use the iOS system 'torch' icon (see below) for my own iOS app.

1. Does Apple allow for the reuse of their icons within other apps?
2. Where can I find the original artwork in a convenient image format?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Apple allow for the reuse of their icons within other apps?

http://www.apple.com/legal/intellectual-property/guidelinesfor3rdparties.html

> You may not use the Apple Logo or any other Apple-owned graphic symbol, logo, or icon on or in connection with web sites, products, packaging, manuals, promotional/advertising materials, or for any other purpose except pursuant to an express written trademark license from Apple, such as a reseller agreement.

Comment: then again, [here's an opposite opinion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156065/does-apple-reject-apps-that-use-images-used-in-apples-apps)

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I'll trust the explicit statement from Apple over an opinion. Some folks may get through review despite using Apple's icons but I wouldn't want that sword hanging over my head on a popular app.